# Can Ebean generate Microsoft SQL Server DDL correctly?

Tags: playframework-2.0, azure-sql-database, ddl, ebean

I successfully connected with Windows Azure DB using Microsoft's driver and in general, communication works, however I found that DDL generated by Ebean is not compatible with MS's specification for an example it uses `auto_increment` instead of `identity` don't ever try to use `nvarchar`, `ntext` fields etc.

Actually, currently I'm managing my Azure's schema manually however I'm just curious if `Ebean` can do that at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at the Ebean source code, it seems that [MsSQL is not well supported](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.avaje/ebean/2.7.3/com/avaje/ebean/config/dbplatform/MsSqlServer2005Platform.java), since very few adjustments are made.

You should consider to adapt it to your need and submit a patch to the Ebean guys.

Also, you could try to use your own [DatabasePlatform](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.avaje/ebean/2.7.3/com/avaje/ebean/config/dbplatform/DatabasePlatform.java) implementation, and setting it in the [Ebean ServerConfig](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.avaje/ebean/2.7.3/com/avaje/ebean/config/ServerConfig.java#ServerConfig.setDatabasePlatform%28com.avaje.ebean.config.dbplatform.DatabasePlatform%29).

For info, the factory which detects the the database type can be found [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.avaje/ebean/2.7.3/com/avaje/ebeaninternal/server/core/DatabasePlatformFactory.java).

Comment: Thx, finally I disabled EbeanPlugin and wrote my own (based on the original). Unfortunately current version of Ebean in stable Play is 2.7.3 and I'm still meeting new problems. Nota bene: Ebean finds proper platform basing on connection URL. I confirmed it in first step, to make sure, there's no stupid mistake in my conf.